# How to reduce timing to find the integer numbers a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, m of this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I use by hand to get this result
$$\sqrt{48+5 \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{27+4\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{12+3 \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}}}=1+4 \sqrt{3}.$$

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[48+5Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[27+4Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[12+3Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[4+2Sqrt[3]]]]]]//TeXForm
```

How to find the integer numbers `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, m` with a short time?

```
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, m} /. 
 Solve[{Sqrt[a + b Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[c + d Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[e + f Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[g + h Sqrt[3]]]]] == k + m Sqrt[3], 1 <= a <= 50,  1 <= b <= 20, 1 <= c <= 50,  1 <= d <= 50, 1 <= e <= 50,  1 <= f <= 50, 1 <= g <= 50,  1 <= h <= 50, 1 <= k <= 50,  1 <= m <= 50}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, m}, Integers]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy, there is an infinite number of integer possibilities:

```
i = Sqrt[a + b Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[c + d Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[e + f Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[g + h Sqrt[3]]]]];
z = (((y^2 - a - b Sqrt[3])^2 - c - d Sqrt[3])^2 - e - f Sqrt[3])^2 //Expand;
{gs, hs} = CoefficientList[Collect[z, Sqrt[3]] /. Sqrt[3] -> p, p];
```

We parametrize by giving values for all parameters but `g` and `h` and find the remaining `g` and `h`:

```
subs1 = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, k -> 7, m -> 8};
subs2 = Join[subs1, {g -> (gs /. subs1), h -> (hs /. subs1)}]
(* {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, k -> 7, m -> 8, 
   g -> 590022698888673277276, h -> 340649743173450268272} *)
```

Now the verification:

```
FullSimplify[i /. subs2]
(* 7 + 8 Sqrt[3] *)
```

as expected.